# Can't load dynamic shared library at runtime including another shared library in C++

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

I'm trying to implement a design similar to the one described here:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3687

I've got a core projects which compiles into an executable binary. I also want to have shared libraries loaded at runtime using `dlopen()`. Now I'm facing the problem that there are some classes which should be known in the core project and also in all of the loaded libraries. I thought I'd put them together in another shared library which gets linked to all of them at compilation. Everything seems to compile fine but during loading the shared library `ConnectionModule.so` dlopen returns no handle and dlerror says 'undefined symbol: _ZTV17PipelineProcessor' where `PipelineProcessor` is a class defined and implemented in the shared library which should be compiled in every addition shared library.

Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong with my implementation or is this design just doomed to fail?

some code here:

loading of library at runtime

```
#include "../SharedHeaders/SharedInEveryLibrary.h"
// ...
map<string, maker_t*, less<string> > module_library;
// ...
void *hndl = dlopen(library_file_path, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (hndl == nullptr) {
    Logger::error << "Could not load library " << library_file_name << ": " << dlerror() << endl;
    exit(-1);
}
```

ConditionModule.h (should be loaded at runtime)

```
#pragma once
#include "../SharedHeaders/SharedInEveryLibrary.h"

class ConditionModule : public B {
    public:
        A* processRequest(X* data) override; // implemented at ConditionModule.cpp
};

extern "C" {
    A *maker() {
        return new ConditionModule;
    }
    class proxy {
        public:
            proxy() {
                module_library["condition_module"] = maker;
            }
    };
    proxy p;
}
```

... and of course aome of the content of SharedInEveryLibrary.h

```
class Z; // gets implemented later, I guess it's not important

struct X {
    int something;
    // ...
};

class A {
    public:
        virtual void setSomeData(X* v_some_data);
        virtual A* process(Z* data) = 0;
    protected:
        X* some_data;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        A* process(Z* data) override;
        virtual A* processRequest(X* data) = 0;
};

typedef A* maker_t();
extern map<string, maker_t*, less<string> > module_library;
```

EDIT -----
Forgot to mention that I currently develop only with Linux as compilation target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this design. But when you dlopen() a shared library, all it's symbols need to be resolved. Your error means that you do not have the path to .so your library depends on in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. To check what library it needs, use

```
ldd <your library.so>
```

Than add the directory where this library resides to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: ldd was a good point. when I ran it first on my ConditionModule it said "not found" since i copied the compiled file somewhere else and the relative path couldn't be resolved. Now I moved SharedInEveryLibrary to /usr/lib/ and ldd finds it now. However the error while executing the program persists. Even if I add /usr/lib/ additionally to LD_LIBRARY_PATH which was originally empty.

Comment: Ok, 5 more minutes of googling with the right phrases did the trick. My Problem was that I did not tell the linker that I Wanne have dynamic libraries. I had to add -E to the LDFLAGS